# Building Dual Function buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have two buttons each with similar functions.
The first function is that when clicked, they  will display a specific menu attributed to them. I.E. 'buttonOne' shows menu one when clicked and 'buttonTwo' shows menu two in place of menu one and vice versa. Only one menu should show at a time and they house the same spot on the screen when displayed.

The second function is to change the color of the button that was last clicked so as to indicate which menu is being shown.  The other button should revert to its unclicked style.

I have been able to figure out how to get the button to change style and in a practice forum, I can get one menu to display and hide with the style change, but have not been able to bring it over to my main code or account for the second button.  Below is a condensed version of the code.  The content in the viewers are anchored to items in the menu.  That is why I want the user to be able to switch visible menus.  I am aware that the second function in this code is not in the script portion.  I expect that it would mirror the function for the first button. So to save space, I left it out.

```
 <body>
  <section id="main_body">
    <section id="nav_area">
      <nav class="viewer_nav" id="menu_one">
        <ul>
         <li>Item 1 - href'd to view_area_one</li>
          <li>Item 2 - href'd to view_area_one</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <nav class="viewer_nav" id="menu_two">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 3 - href'd to view_area_two</li>
          <li>Item 4 - href'd to view_area_two</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>

    <div id="content_area">


  <div class="viewer_class" id="view_area_one">
    <input type= "button" value="Viewer One" id="buttonOne" class="button_style"  onclick="switchViewer()" />
   <p>Content for menu two will go here and user can jump to a section that is linked in menu_one</p>
  </div>

  <div class="viewer_class" id="view_area_two">
   <input type= "button" value="Viewer Two" id="buttonTwo" class="button_style"  onclick="switchViewertwo()" />
   <p>Content for menu two will go here and user can jump to a section that is linked in menu_two</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script>
 function switchViewer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("viewer_two");
  var y = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.value="Viewer One";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your buttons and use radiobuttons instead. They already have built-in the functionality to replace the previous selected value. This way, you can show a different div for every element of the radio group, by styling it in pure CSS, like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-menu input').on('change', function(){
    //$('.content-div').hide();
    $('.content-div[data-div=' + $(this).data('div') + ']').toggle(this.checked);
  });
})
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
  position:absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label[for*=radio-menu],
label[for*=js-menu]{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #7689a9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label[for*=radio-menu]:hover {
  background: #4d658d;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #152c55;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-div,
.content-div{
  display: none;
}

.menu-1:checked ~ .div-1,
.menu-2:checked ~ .div-2,
.menu-3:checked ~ .div-3,
.menu-4:checked ~ .div-4{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Same-level, pure CSS</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="menu" class="menu-1" id="radio-menu-1" />
  <label for="radio-menu-1">Menu 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="menu" class="menu-2" id="radio-menu-2" />
  <label for="radio-menu-2">Menu 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="menu" class="menu-3" id="radio-menu-3" />
  <label for="radio-menu-3">Menu 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="menu" class="menu-4" id="radio-menu-4" />
  <label for="radio-menu-4">Menu 4</label>
  <div class="menu-div div-1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="menu-div div-2">Content 2</div>
  <div class="menu-div div-3">Content 3</div>
  <div class="menu-div div-4">Content 4</div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Different Level, JS</h1>
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-2" data-div="1" id="js-menu-1" />
    <label for="js-menu-1">Menu 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-2" data-div="2" id="js-menu-2" />
    <label for="js-menu-2">Menu 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-2" data-div="3" id="js-menu-3" />
    <label for="js-menu-3">Menu 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-2" data-div="4" id="js-menu-4" />
    <label for="js-menu-4">Menu 4</label>
  </nav>
  <div class="div-container">
    <div class="content-div" data-div="1">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="content-div" data-div="2">
      Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="content-div" data-div="3">
      Content 3
    </div>
    <div class="content-div" data-div="4">
      Content 4
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

You can also use a small snippet to hide all content and show only the corresponding container for the checked "button", like the second example.

Comment: Thank you for the response and it's a very good idea.  Unfortunately, my end product requires that both of the content areas to be visible and only one menu.  The users may need to look at different content from both viewers in combination.  Something in viewer one that is related to something different in viewer two.

Comment: Then you can replace the radiobuttons for checkboxes. Check out the updated example. Also, you can use the jquery function `toggle()` with a boolean parameter to turn on or off the divs on command.